# How to create full screen dialogs in Android?

Tags: android

I have the following setup:

The main activity has a fragment container and a bottom navigator. When pressing the tabs fragment container content is changed accordingly.

Inside each of these fragments I want to be able to launch a **full screen** dialog for editing content.

This article explains how to cope with fragments with children:

https://medium.com/@bherbst/managing-the-fragment-back-stack-373e87e4ff62

The code for the article:

https://github.com/bherbst/FragmentBackStackSample

This example matches my setup quite accurate, but...

I can't make the full screen dialog fragment **cover** the bottom navigator. The navigator is disabled (it does no longer respond to clicks), but it is visible. I wan't the dialog to cover full screen.

How to resolve?

Thanks, Ove

Comment: share a screenshot of the problem statement!

Comment: Please check if you place fragment placeholder in a correct layout. Also, check an elevation of the BottomSheets.